# Should i respect the order of instructions when i'm using Asynchronous tasks (std::async Function Template)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous

I was working on a multi-threaded program when I crossed a case in which when I ask some asynchronous implementations like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>

using namespace std::chrono;

int increment(int i){
     i++;
     std::this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(5));

     return i;
}

int main()
{

    int x(0),y(0);

    std::future<int> result = std::async(std::launch::async,
                                         [](int i)mutable throw()->
                                         int{
                                              i++;
                                              std::this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(5));
                                              return i;
                                          }, y);
    x=increment(x);
    y = result.get();
    return 0;

}
```

Focusing on the two instructions `x=increment(x)` and `y = result.get()` should they be in this order, or is there another explanation? Because:

Case 1:

```
x=increment(x);
y = result.get();
```

Time Execution : 5 seconds (As expected !)

Case 2:

```
y = result.get();
x=increment(x);
```

Time Execution : 10 seconds

Is there any logical explanations to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y = result.get();
x=increment(x);
```

In this case, the main thread will be blocked until the created thread finishes its work because `get` block the thread where it's working until it finishes its work

```
x=increment(x);
y = result.get();
```

Here is no blocking because  `y = result.get();` comes at the end and this way is the way threads should work.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get